# Failing to configre jndi.properties Flume for Oracle AQ

Tags: jms, jndi, flume, oracle-aq

I'm trying to connect my `Apache Flume` app source to `Oracle AQ`.
`jndi.properties` is in the classpath and configured as follows:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://my.db.url
java.naming.security.principal=remote
java.naming.security.credentials=remotepwd
```

I am getting the following error in the log:

```
Source jmsSource has been removed due to an error during configuration
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Could not create initial context oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory provider tcp://my.db.url
....
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: The configuration of the AQjmsInitialContext is not complete.
The configuration must contain datasource or (db_url,java.naming.security.principal,java.naming.security.credentials) or both
```

I have copied the `java.naming.security.principal=remote` `java.naming.security.credentials=remotepwd` from an example and I don't really know what are the values I need to insert.

Any suggestions about how to configure the `jndi.properties` file correct?

Comment: How about specifying the url via `db_url=tcp://my.db.url` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message (which wasn't clear to me either until I looked at the sources), db url is specified via the `db_url` property. So you would like to have something like

`java.naming.factory.initial=oracle.jms.AQjmsInitialContextFactory
db_url=tcp://my.db.url
java.naming.security.principal=remote
java.naming.security.credentials=remotepwd`